# Why does my call back function not run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, database

```
var user_col = db.collection('users');
var cursor = user_col.findOne({email:'testuser1@test.com', password:'test'}, function(err,doc){
            console.log("THIS IS A TEST");
    });
```

The problem with this code is the callback function does not seem to run.
THIS IS A TEST does not get outputted.

I am connected to a database, db is passed into this function as an argument. What are the possible problems?

Comment: The most obvious possible problem is that no such document exists. Are you sure there is a document with those criteria - I'm pretty sure the callback won't be invoked if no such document exists. A `find()` might be a better option to debug this.

Comment: Is the connection being explicitly closed at any other point? That could be acting before the query can finish.

Answer (score 2):

`findOne()` doesn't receive a callback as second parameter, the second one is a `projection` which means that if you define it will only return the specified parameters `db.collection.findOne(query, projection)`. That's way your callback is not been executed.
[findOne documentation here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)

[Examples here](http://www.journaldev.com/6197/mongodb-findone-example-using-mongo-shell-and-java-driver)

**Updated:**

According to the comments seems to be [this docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne) *(my mistake)*, but the issue was the missing **second parameter `findOne(query, options, callback)`**

Comment: Note that you've linked to the Shell API. The [Node.js/JavaScript API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne) should support a callback as the 2nd or 3rd argument (`options` are optional).

Comment: And doesn't work if you do:

user_col.findOne({email:'testuser1@test.com', password:'test'}, null, function(err,doc){
            console.log("THIS IS A TEST");
    });
¡

Comment: @Matho: you're comparing apples and oranges - you're in the completely wrong environment. This has nothing to do with the mongo shell command.

Comment: @mnemosyn i realize sorry about that if the second comment doesn't help i'll remove the answer